# Symfony Doctrine Group By

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I need to get result from my database as associative array. I have gardens and families that related to this gardens as (One to Many). So for each garden i need to get array of families. So garden must be key, and array of families - it is a values. So i tried:

```
public function getFamiliesInGardens($client)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('g');

    $qb
        ->select(['g.name as garden', 'family.name', 'family.id'])
        ->join('g.growing', 'growing')
        ->join('growing.plant', 'plant')
        ->join('plant.family', 'family')
        ->where('g.client = :client')
        ->orderBy('g.name')
        ->addOrderBy('growing.endDate', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter('client', $client);

    $grow = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

    return $grow;
}
```

I got:

```
[0] => array(3) {
    ["garden"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>string(9) "Brassicas"
    ["id"]=> int(13)
}
[1] =>
    array(3) {
    ["garden"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=> string(13) "Miscellaneous"
    ["id"]=> int(18)
    }
```

But i expect:

```
[0] => array(1) {
    ["1"] => array(2) {
        [0] => array(2) {
            ["name"] =>string(9) "Brassicas"
            ["id"] => int(13)
        },
        [1] => array(2) {
            ["name"]=>string(9) "Miscellaneous"
            ["id"]=> int(18)
        },
    }
}
```

If i will add group by garden, result will be the same as first, but garden will be chosed once without repeat. Same for family. So, what can i change to get array: garden => families?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this use case 3 years ago where I hoped the same. However, `GROUP BY` does not work that way.

You would have to manually iterate over the records and group them as you require. For example, something like this:

```
$gardens = ....
$groups = [];
for ( $gardens as $g ){
    if (!array_key_exists($g['id'], $groups)){
        $groups[$g['id']] = [];
    }

    $groups[$g['id']][] = $g;
}
```